# How to populate Enum from the values retrieved from Database

Tags: botframework

Looking at the example here at [Message Controller for Pizza Example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/PizzaBot/Controllers/MessagesController.cs), if I want to populate Size or Kind based on some user input and make a call to the database, how would I do that?

So far as I know, there is not an easy way to populate the Enum at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this hasn't been implemented yet. I took a look inside https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/FormFlow/FormBuilder.cs and found this:

```
    internal static void TypePaths(Type type, string path, List<string> paths)
    {
        if (type.IsClass)
        {
            if (type == typeof(string))
            {
                paths.Add(path);
            }
            else if (type.IsIEnumerable())
            {
                var elt = type.GetGenericElementType();
                if (elt.IsEnum)
                {
                    paths.Add(path);
                }
                else
                {
                    // TODO: What to do about enumerations of things other than enums?
                }
            }
            else
            {
                FieldPaths(type, path, paths);
            }
        }
        else if (type.IsEnum)
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(bool))
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
        else if (type.IsIntegral())
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
        else if (type.IsDouble())
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
        else if (type.IsNullable() && type.IsValueType)
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            paths.Add(path);
        }
    }
```

Notice the TODO about enumerations other than enums.

Outside of the FormBuilder we can use `PromptDialog.Choice` which takes an `IEnumerable<>` of your options.

It is possible to chain dialogs together, so you may have to split your `FormDialog` into two with the PromptDialog in-between.

Alternatively take a fork of BotBuilder and implement the TODO!